# Up/Down goes ~” phrases

Tags: grammar

There is a Sesame Street song ”Up goes the castle”. I also heard “Down goes ~” in English casting of pro game match. Why is the order of words changed in these phrases? Are there any similar phrases other than up/down - go combination?

Answer (score 6):

**Up** and **down** are adverbs. If an adverb (or adjective) fronts a clause, historically, this was followed by inversion: "Dearly do I love thee." "Bravely spoke he." ("Long was the road.")

In broad terms, other than as a poetic or literary device, this convention is now only used with locative adverbs and adverbial phrases: "**Here** is the key and **there** is the door" "**In this house lived Sir John Smith." "To the west lies the river and to the east, the mountains.**"

Comment: It's also used for emphasis in sentences like "Bang goes my chance of a free lunch".

Comment: Nowhere is this more evident than with negative adverbs. They don't have to be fronted,  but if they are, this *forces* the verb to come second and the subject third.

Comment: @RosieF: Hardly did I expect to see such a deftly self-referential example as yours! (Rarely do my efforts work so well! :)